# display xml elements inside xml using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Ia using XSLT 1.0 and I do have a XML while looks like this

```
<item name="note"><value>&lt;p&gt;Add the &amp;lt;bean&amp;gt; tag pased below to the &amp;lt;beans&amp;gt; element in this file .... </value></item>
```

I want to display it like this in HTML

```
Add the <bean> tag passed below to the <beans> element in this file.
```

Note here that the <p> will be converted to a paragraph tag as I use disable-output-escaping= yes.

This is what I have in my xslt

```
<xsl:template match="item[@name='note']">
    <xsl:value-of select="value" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>
```

With this xslt it ignores the bean and beans xml and it does not get displayed in the page. How do I make sure to display it the way I want it?

Comment: This is over-escaped --- return to whoever producet it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that some of your entities have been "double escaped".
`&amp;lt;bean&amp;gt;` should be `&lt;bean&gt;`

Comment: I cannot change that as this XML is actually displayed in a WYSIWYG editor and if I remove the &amp; it does not display the XML there.